# Same style for two elements in table th and tr. How to avoid redundancy?

Tags: css

Right now I have the following:

```
table th.bordered {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table td.borderd {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

How can I put this in a single rule??

Answer (score 3):

Billy's is technically correct, but there's an even better way:

```
table .bordered {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Or even (if you want to use it on something other than tables):

```
.bordered {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Doing one of these two will help prevent being overly-specific, which will make maintaining it a lot easier.

Comment: "Doing one of these two will help prevent being overly-specific" Well, unless the author wants to use the class `bordered` in other places within `tables` and doesn't want these styles applied.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - True, but "bordered", like snjesko pointed out, is quite vague and probably better off being refactored to be more meaningful. Also, starting out with `table th.bordered` prevents using that as an override.

Comment: very true, I see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add to Billy's answer that you could potentially shorten this to

```
table .bordered {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

or even

```
.bordered {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

if specificity is not an issue.

Performance would be slightly better as the browser doesn't have to check for parent elements after it has found an element with the class "bordered". But in most cases that would be negligible.

You might also want to be more semantic with your class name than just "bordered". Something like "highlightColumn" or "errorCell". Just in case you decide to use an orange background instead of a red border or want to use different borders for different purposes, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine them like so:

```
table th.bordered, table td.bordered {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: You can drop element selector: `table .bordered {}`.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov - You could, but I'd recommend keeping it there incase the OP wants to add a '.bordered' class to other elements within his TABLE and wants those elements to be styled differently.